# Arrays in Azure Table Storage Entities (Non-Byte)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm looking to store arrays in Azure Table entities. At present, the only type of array supported natively is byte-array, limited to 64k length. The size is enough, but I'd like to store arrays of longs, doubles and timestamps in an entity.

I can obviously cast multiple bytes to the requested type myself, but I was wondering if there's any best-practice to achieve that.

To clarify, these are fixed length arrays (e.g. 1000 cells) associated with a single key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying to think of a nice way to do this other than the method you've already mentioned, and I'm at a loss.  The simplest solution I can come up with is to take the array, binary serialize it and store in a binary array property.

Other options I've come up with but dismissed:

1. If storing it natively is important, you could keep this information in another child table (I know Azure Tables don't technically have relationships, but that doesn't mean you can't represent this type of thing).  The downside of this being that it will be considerably slower than your original.
2. Take the array, XML serialize it and store it in a string property.  This would mean that you could see the contents of your array when using 3rd party data explorer tools and you could run (inefficient) queries that look for an exact match on the contents of the array.
3. Use [Lokad Cloud fat entities](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities) to store your data.  This essentially takes you're whole object, binary serializes it and splits the results into 64kb blocks across the properties of the table entity.  This does solve problems like the one you're experiencing, but you will only be able to access your data using tools that support this framework.

Comment: Or you can take the code from Lokad.Cloud and reuse it as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a Azure table storage client, called Lucifure Stash, which supports arrays, enums, large data, serialization, public and private properties and fields and more.

You can get it at https://github.com/hocho/LucifureStash

Comment: The link leads in a wrong site, perhaps this is the correct url? https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=lucifurestash

Answer (score 3):

If you have just a key-value collection to store, then you can also **check out Azure BLOBs**. They can rather efficiently store arrays of up to 25M time-value points per single blob (with a random access within the dataset).

Comment: I wish I'd though of this when I was compiling my list, I guess I got stuck on tables.  It would be possible to just serialize (binary/XML, doesn't matter) and store the whole object by key.  The big downsides are that there's not great tool support for managing large numbers of blobs and you are restricted to just querying using keys.

Comment: You can suppliment the data with a paired table row.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to store your object in blob storage and need more than one "key" to get it, you can just create an azure table or two or n where you store the key you want to look up and the reference to the exact blob item.

Comment: This is a good option as well, a bit more work but gives more flexibility while still keeping the overall cost low.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the values as csv strings?

Comment: Size limitations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950693/about-azure-table-storage-row-1mb-limit-how-it-counts-for-utf8-code

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize your array as a JSON string using the .NET JavaScript serializer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

This class has a "MaxJsonLength" property you could use to ensure your arrays didn't exceed 64K when you were serializing them. And you can use the same class to deserialize your stored objects.