# About Azure Table Storage Row 1MB Limit, How it counts for UTF8 Code?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Lets first quote:

> Combined size of all of the properties in an entity cannot exceed 1MB.
>   (for a ROW/Entity) from [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx)

**My Questions is**: Since everything is XMLed data, so for 1MB, is 1MB of what, 1MB of ASCII Chars, or 1MB of UTF8 Chars, or something else?

**Sample**:

```
Row1: PartitionKey="A', RowKey="A", Data="A"
Row2: PartitionKey="A', RowKey="A", Data="Ａ"  (this is a UTF8 unicode A)
```

Is Row1 and Row2 same size (in length), or `Row2.Length=Row1.Length+1`?

Comment: I found my answer Row2.Length=Row1.Length+1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Single columns such as "Data" in your example are limited to 64 KB of binary data and single rows are limited to 1 MB of data.  Strings are encoding into binary in the UTF8 format so the limit is whatever the byte size ends up being for your string.  If you want your column to store more than 64 KB of data you can use a technique such as FAT Entity which is provided to you with Lokad (https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud-storage/blob/master/Source/Lokad.Cloud.Storage/Azure/FatEntity.cs).  The technique is pretty simple, you just encode your string to binary and then split the binary across multiple columns.  Then when you want to read the string from the table, you would just re-join the columns again and convert the binary back to a string.

Comment: Do you mean, if ASCII code, I can save 1M chars, but for UTF8 Code, I can only save half?

Comment: UTF8 encoding is not necessarily double the size of ASCII encoding.  Infact if your characters are in the ASCII range of 0-128 the encoding ends up being the same size.  You should look up how UTF8 is encoded.

Comment: So If I save Asian characters, I can only save half the size of pure English? Right

Comment: I am not sure about the encoding for Asian characters but something around that.

Comment: The information that strings are encoded to UTF8 in Azure Table Storage is incorrect. It is UTF16. And that makes a huge difference.

Comment: This is incorrect information about UTF8
Actually MSDN says "String - A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to 64 KB in size."
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx)

Comment: Can confirm, it's `32 * 1024` exactly. `new string('W', 32 * 1024)` OK `new string('W', 32 * 1024 + 1)` NOT OK. You are better off encoding your strings as UTF-8 values yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Azure table row size calculation is quite involved and includes both the size of the property name and its value plus some overhead.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/30/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage.aspx

Edit. Removed statement that earlier said that size calculation was slightly inaccurate. It is quite accurate.